# Lagrangian formulation of an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization

I am a bit puzzled on how the constraints of a given optimization problem pass through the Lagrangian. Given, say, the following problem:
\begin{align}
(P) \qquad \inf_x \,\,\, f(x)  \quad  \text{such that} \quad g_1\geq0,\ldots,g_m\geq 0,
\end{align}
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g_i : x \mapsto g_i(x)$ are polynomials defining a semialgebraic set.

**My first confusion** is whether the Lagrangian problem (under certain assumptions) can be written as (maybe with plus sign?)
\begin{align}
(L1) \qquad \inf_x \sup_t \,\,\, f(x)  - t\sum_{i=1}^mg_i,
\end{align}
where $t$ is the Lagrange multiplier, or as (maybe with plus sign?)
\begin{align}
(L2) \qquad \inf_x \sup_{t_i} \,\,\, f(x)  - \sum_{i=1}^mt_ig_i, \quad \forall i,
\end{align}
where now one has many Lagrange multipliers (one for each constraint).

**My relevant second confusion** is how exactly taking the sup of $t$ or of all $t_i$s guarantees that the constraints are satisfied. In (P) the requirement is clear. However, in (L1) and (L2) it is not clear to me why the constraints are satisfied. If, for example, a certain $g_j <0$, then taking the sup w.r.t. $t_j$ can yield negative infinity.

**Can you provide me some intuition on how exactly the Lagrangian enforces the constraints? Or what I understand wrongfully?**

Comment: The second Lagrangian is (almost) correct, not the first one. We need as many multipliers as constraints. The second problem is that you inverted the order of the operators. Finally, if you want to get some intuition, you will need to check something called the KKT conditions and duality theory.

Comment: I know the KKT optimality conditions and how to derive. However, I am not sure I have good intuition on my question (2nd part). Why is the second one "almost" correct? Due to the plus sign?

Comment: I explained why this is not correct above, you swapped the operators. Regarding the intuition, you will need to do some exercises with KKT and understand what those conditions mean. Finally, what you wrote above does not imply that your constraints are satisfied.